# how to use import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection; in SE Application in Java

Tags: java, package

i want to use this import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

package in my SE application. my purpose is to connect to the webserver to download a image. i found this code while searching. that code was designed to ME application.

can soemone help me to find this for SE application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `new URL(...).openConnection()`

There are plenty of tutorials on [java.net.URL](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) too.

Comment: +1 - J2ME code may need source-code changes to run on J2SE.  Them's the facts.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) provides an alternative API to both `javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection` and `URL.openConnection()`, and much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just include this in your Java project.  It will wrap your J2ME calls so that they work in J2SE.

microemulator-app-swing-2.0.0.jar